# invoke azure blockchain workbench rest api from azure logic app with oauth

Tags: azure, oauth, blockchain, azure-logic-apps

I am using Azure Blockchain workbench. One smart contract is deployed on Azure Blockchain workbench.
I can do everything from workbench front end. But I want to integrate Azure Blockchain workbench backend ( API part ) with Azure logic apps.
In Azure Blockchain workbench backend ( API ) there is POST api to enter data into smart contract. I want to invoke that API endpoint from Azure logic App.
My logic app is like when a row is added to MSSQL database table it will trigger an action which will invoke POST api of Azure Blockchain workbench.
Backend of Azure blockchain workbench is secured with Azure AD oauth. Currently, I am passing raw Bearer token in Azure logic apps by copying it from Inspect elements of browser. And it is working fine with that. But I want to make token dynamic because every time when token expires I have to copy and paste it again from browser to Azure logic app to make it work.
I have confusion with Azure AD oauth.
How to authenticate particular in Azure AD oauth and make API request with that user's auth token ?
If that is not possible with logic app how to generate auth token of particular user ?
( user I want to authenticate is registered in my Azure AD )

[I have also generated token manually using azure AD oauth API. Token generated successfully but it gives error about Unauthorised request in Azure logic apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N7Cx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the logic app trigger shared by you, your logic app is a daemon service triggered based on insertion of row to a sql db table. In such case you will have to implement Client Credentials flow of OAUTH 2.0 to secure the token.
[Microsoft identity platform and the OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)

Comment: I have also generated token manually using Azure AD oauth API. 
Token generated successfully but when I am using that token in Azure logic apps it gives error about unauthorised request. I have attached screenshot in question.

Comment: How are you passing the token and are the permission requested with the token api correct and match up with the permission the resource requires while accessing it?

Comment: I am passing raw token in azure logic apps as 
Bearer <received token> 
I am passing parameters as shown in my screenshot for generating token. I doubt there may be some issue with scope parameter. Can you give any example for that ( Where can I get those list of permission which i want to specify for a user ) ?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the official Microsoft doco for this?
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure-blockchain-workbench/)
Samples can be found at [link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/blockchain/tree/master/blockchain-workbench/rest-api-samples)